# When and how would clocks be invented on a cloud-enshrouded planet?

Tags: time

Suppose a habitable planet is perpetually enshrouded with clouds but still has enough light seeping through to make lit and unlit portions of a day, and has an intelligent tool-making species living on it. Assume primitive civilization of some sort starts to develop. When would they start to need clocks, and how would they satisfy this need?

Keep in mind that the first "clocks" on Earth are likely over 5500 years old, and probably older. A simple vertical stick in the ground would have sufficed, but sticks of course rot. However, those first clocks on Earth were made in regions where the sky was not cloudy all day.

This question asks about the first clocks on a world where the sky is cloudy all day, everywhere, and remains cloudy all day (and all night) throughout the year.

Note: I am not asking about timing how long it takes to cook an egg. I'm asking about scheduling a meeting thirty days from now at 2:00 in the afternoon, or since it's a primitive society, scheduling a meeting thirty days from now sometime in the afternoon. Water clocks were notoriously imprecise, as were hourglasses.

Comment: Oh, the ancients had other kinds of time-measuring devices besides sun-dials. Sand-glasses, water clocks, calibrated candles... (Sand-glasses remained in widespread use to the end of the 19th century, for example for measuring the speed of ships. Originally, *knots* referred to the number of actual knots tied on the rope attached to a wooden log, which passed through the sailors fingers while a standard sand-glass emptied.)

Comment: Is this world pitch black or just dim? because if light is at least somewhat present during the day then you could tell what time it is based on how bright the clouds look

Comment: @redfrogcrab Just dim. There's still a dim daylight period and a dark nighttime period. Maybe a bit Venus-like, but not quite as bad as that. (Even Venus's surface has day and night.)

Comment: @AlexP Water clocks were a much later development than sundials, which in turn were a much later development than obelisks, and which in turn were most likely a much later development than a stick in the ground. I suspect the need for timekeeping goes back in time as far as civilization does.

Comment: We don't really have any proof (or even a hint of a proof) that obelisks were ever used as the gnomons of sundials; as far as we can tell, obelisks were not intended to be anything more than visually striking monuments. And the oldest sundials we actually have were obviously made as sundials, complete with hour divisions. (Perhaps suprisingly, the oldest water clocks ever found are roughly of the same age as the oldest sundials ever found, about the middle of the 2nd milennium BCE.)

Comment: If the sun is hidden by the clouds, then getting a rough idea of the time just by looking at the position of the sun and the lengths of the shadows becomes harder. So I would expect a clock to be invented ***sooner*** than on Earth, because it's more needed.

Comment: @AlexP I'll admit that whether obelisks were used as crude timekeeping devices is debated. That said, I have plenty of sources that say they were. Regarding those very old sundials, all of those found already had hour divisions. (That's how we know they were sundials.) Certainly some more primitive timekeeping device preceded them.

Comment: How fast does your clock have to tick? A tree is a clock that counts years as soon as you figure out the relationship between tree rings and years of growth.

Comment: @gs "Let's meet thirty days from now halfway into the afternoon" is good enough.

Comment: *Why* do you need a clock? Calendars are important to the sustenance farmer, which is what everyone was. If the sun is up, it's work time. Time of day is for navigation (of the sea) and the logistics thereof (trains). *Thousands* of years after you've your first clock, *then* we can talk about timepieces. "Certainly some more primitive timekeeping device preceded them." ... If it's not on this page, then no : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock - certainly nothing that was more accurate than water clocks and hourglasses.

Comment: @Mazura This is StackExchange, so one question per question. Asking about a calendar is a different question.

Comment: @AlexP 19th century?  Heck, we still use sand-glass timers today.  Granted they're mostly for recreational purposes nowadays, but e.g. a lot of board games come with a sand timer.

Comment: You ask for clocks. There are a couple of vital uses for calendars: predicting the seasons for planting (is it a warm spell or has winter really ended), and for shipping (the safe time in the Mediterranean was known in some detail to the Roman Empire). It may be cloudy, but it gets light and dark and people might postulate the existence of some regular passage of a light source.

More interesting to me - if you are always in fog, what would flight be like?

Comment: @RichardKirk Those are different questions, and as is the case with my response to Mazura's comment, my response is that it is best on StackExchange to keep a question to one specific question. Changing my question to asking about calendars would be unfair to those who already answered my question about keeping time. Could an intelligent species advance beyond the stone age level (let alone flight) on a perpetually cloudy world? That's also an interesting question, but it too is a different question.

Comment: @DavidHammen I didn't know there had been a previous question about calendars. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 key purposes of Time:

1: future planning events and co-ordination (Meet me at 3 pm!)
2: Time elapsed (Cook for 5 minutes on high).

As others have eluded to, Hour glasses/Sand clocks/Water clocks would fulfill the function of point 2 - but these answers, although good - don't address a unified agreed sense of 'time'

Function 1, however is where a time system based off of the workable hours in a day becomes super relevant - you have a 'start' and a 'stop' period and then you subdivide that into approximately uniform graduations - these same graduations are used for function 2 for simplicity - but it doesn't answer how we get there.

My answer:

**Tidal Based Time**

You didn't specify if your fictional world has a moon or other heavenly bodies - but I'm going to presume it has one and that like on Earth, these cause Tidal flows. The Tidal flows are not obscured.

Now the Tidal flow isn't precise initially - but it's good enough and regular enough to know within an acceptable margin of error for a primitive society.

The other reason Tidal Flows are a great idea? Spring Tides - now we not only have Time, but we have a Calendar! Spring Tides occur at Full Moon or New Moon - giving us approximately 2 weeks (again, assuming a Moon that works like ours - but you can fiddle the variables as you see fit).

You can also add in King Tides (or Perigean Spring tides - to use the correct term) as denoting either changes in season or significant events (Religious or otherwise) etc. etc.

Comment: That's a neat idea, particularly for a planet doesn't have a large moon (or even worse, two large moons). Surprisingly, we've only had good models of the tides for about 250 years; this was an area where Isaac Newton pretty much failed. (Tides in the North Sea and English Channel are notoriously complex.) It was Laplace's dynamic theory of the tides that turned the boat around (pun intended).

Comment: Another way to get seasons and years (and hence a primitive calendar) is to notice that the time the sky remains lit changes over the course of a year. That's assuming the planet either has a non-zero obliqueness or a non-zero orbital eccentricity. I'm liking this answer more and more as it not only yields a primitive clock but also yields a primitive calendar.

Comment: I've chosen this over the top-rated answer for multiple reasons. The key reason is that it's rather primitive, which is what I wanted. Another reason is that evidence for the first tide-keeping society would eventually be wiped out by the ravages of time. The species would forget that they kept time by the tides before they invented water clocks. Moreover, a tidal clock is in a sense a kind of water clock. It would motivate some bright young individual to invent a drain-based water clock. While this assumes a coastal species, there's nothing wrong with that in a world building exercise.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Awesome, you are most welcome - good luck with the rest of your story!

Answer (score 21):

**Clocks don't exist to tell you when the sun will rise and set, they exist to coordinate the activities of people and events**

When will clocks be invented on your world? Just as soon as the inconvenience of getting people together for an important meeting or activity outweighs the value of not having a clock (or the first time dinner is burned, whichever comes first).

From a practical perspective, clocks have nothing to do with the sun. Yes, here on Earth where we have a clear view of many celestial events, the development of clocks (and time keeping) was hugely light based. But as time progressed (hah...), we discovered that celestial events weren't as predictable as we needed them to be. OUr need for really precise time has forced us to define time (e.g., the [definition and measurement of a second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second)) in ways that respect, but exclude celestial events.

Long story short, you don't need light to have a clock.

As our own [history of timekeeping devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_timekeeping_devices) suggests, there are many ways (and reasons!) to keep time. Even on your world, there will be (or, should be...) seasons. A cold season, a stormy season, a warm season, a "light" period, a "dark" period.... So the basic divisions incorporating the sun and the planet's rotation and orbit exist, just not as precisely as here on Earth.

Sand, water, incense, pendulums, candles... Anything with a reasonably predictable *rate of consumption* can be used to create a clock. In the end, your good people will end up with gears, then electronics, then atomics, for precision time.

In short, your people will basically build the same kind of timekeeping devices Humans did. They just won't depend on sundials much because they'll be too imprecise too early in your people's history.

Comment: Regarding "Clocks don't exist to tell you when the sun will rise and set, they exist to coordinate the activities of people and events": Exactly. Back when it took humans a long day to travel a mere 20 or so kilometers, "meet with me next Thursday" would have been good enough. At what point did "meet with me next Thursday" become not good enough?

Comment: Note also that civilization managed fine for a long time with pretty crappy clocks, until navigation during long-distance sea voyages brought tougher requirements to timekeeping. So, the sophistication of timekeeping tech will likely be driven in part by other activities that nominally have nothing to do with knowing the time. And, if your very cloudy world has no oceans, they might be satisfied with rudimentary clocks for millennia.

Comment: @DavidHammen It became "not good enough" the day someone needed to say, "meet me at 2pm...." As Tom mentioned, clocks are good for a lot of things, like calculating distances and establishing the time for something to occur, like a race. We've had clocks from 5500BC for a reason (more or less the time "next Thursday" wasn't good enough anymore :-) ).

Comment: This reminds me of my favorite quote ever, from Plautus (not Plato): *"The Gods confound the man who first found out how to distinguish the hours. Confound him, too, who in this place set up a sundial to cut and hack my days so wretchedly into small pieces."*

Comment: *"Back when it took humans a long day to travel a mere 20 or so kilometers"* A long day of less than 4 hours? 20km is not that long a distance.

Comment: People accidently invent clocks all the time. A staple of Japanese gardens is a [deer scarer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shishi-odoshi). A tube of bamboo that swivels on a pivot. When it fills with water it tips and dumps the water. Then returns upright with a loud thump that scares deer away. It's effectively a water clock that doesn't keep time.

Comment: @Stef 20 km is a short distance if you have a car. It's a moderate distance if you have a horse. If you're on foot, it qualifies as a somewhat long day's hike. Even well into the middle ages, there were plenty of people who had never in their lifetime traveled more than 20 km from their home town.

Comment: @tom +1. **As soon as you need to know your longitude in the middle of the sea**, they will offer money to anyone who can make a *timepiece*. Otherwise you don't need to know when it's 2PM; just that it's 30 days later, which is easy: stick 30 sticks into the ground, one per day. You wake up and go to the place we said to meet in 30d, and wait. If the economy doesn't demand it, then you can't have it. In a world w/o clocks, if no one knows when it's 2PM, then no one needs to know when it's 2PM. What kind of drive-yourself-into-the-ground-20th-century-stupidness has you in such a rush?

Comment: @DavidHammen When walking how ‘long’ it is has a lot to do with terrain and experience. For a novice hiker in rugged terrain, 20km is definitely a grueling day of hiking. For someone with lots of experience traveling on foot crossing reasonably good terrain (mostly flat and not swampy), it’s a bit more than half a day at a reasonably leisurely pace, or maybe a third of a day moving particularly fast (speaking from experience as someone who has actually covered such distances on foot before). Oh, and the travel habits of medieval peasants had more to do with not needing to go further than that.

Comment: Fwiw, when I was a bit younger I would do a lot of hiking, and I could cover an average of 40km in easy parts with a personal record of 78km in one day. Nowadays I would be incapable of that. Habits definitely make a huge difference.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Also for what you're carrying with you.  Medieval people couldn't afford random travelling for fun, so it was always travel with a purpose.  That means you're carrying stuff to sell (or leading a horse/ox and cart, or pushing a handcart), or you're driving livestock. And don't forget that you need to break camp in the morning and set up camp again at the end of the day, which is a longer process if you need to build a fire.

Comment: @Mazura That doesn't work in this planet. Time doesn't tell you longitude. You compare time of celestial events between two points, and with knowledge of the rotation rate of the Earth, you determine longitude. (e.g. if the sun rises at 3 PM at home, and your clock says it rises at 3 AM, then you're halfway around the Earth) However, the planet is enshrouded in clouds so you can't even see the Sun, much less stars, so you're stuck. You'd need for somebody to get the idea for laser ring gyros or navigation satellites first.

Comment: @DavidHammen "next Thursday" would be way too vague if you're meeting with different groups of people on a particular day (so if more than 1 person is living within the same few kilometers) or if you'd like to plan your day out (which you don't even need more than 1 person for). So basically "meet with me next Thursday" was not good enough (for all time specification needs) from the moment that people started using it.

Comment: @user71659 Actually, that might make a pretty good question for this Stack. If I knew the average sailing speed and the time, then I know distance without celestial objects - but that requires having a way of determining wind speed. In other words, it's still possible to use a clock to determine distance, but not necessarily (other than as a byproduct) longitude.

Comment: @JBH Longitude is distance. Unlike latitude, the prime meridian is arbitrarily defined, so you are in effect measuring distance from a human construct. You don't need to know wind speed or sea currents, you measure and double integrate over time the acceleration of the boat, that's how inertial nav works. Your other option is to measure the relative arrival times of synchronized signals, audio or electromagnetic. GPS, and land-based predecessors LORAN and OMEGA are nothing more than broadcasting clocks.

Comment: @user71659 No, longitude is a *location.* It can be derived by knowing how much distance you've traveled, or it can be derived by calculating it based on known celestial observations. But you've *really missed my point.* The interesting question to ask is, how can someone from the 1500s calculate ocean distance if they don't have access to sextants, clocks, or any celestial objects? (Considering the OP is asking about first-use of clocks, defaulting to electronics is 100% off-base. People measured distance millennia before any electronics were invented.)

Comment: i do like this answer (very much so, in fact), but I was after something more primitive than water clocks. I instead accepted the answer that uses tides because it is so nicely primitive.

Comment: @JBH Nope. Distance and location are the same thing. Location implies distance from a reference point. In longitude, we used to define the reference point as a surface perpendicular to the rotation axis of the Earth. Today, we define the reference point based on an arbitrarily truncated gravity model which is not directly on the rotation axis. And the Chinese developed  such [dead-reckoning systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South-pointing_chariot) in the 5th century BC.

Comment: @JBH While you may assume the equator has some magical properties with regards to celestial navigation, it doesn't because of the Earth's axial tilt. You have to know the date (i.e. time). With inertial nav, the rotation of the Earth is sensed, but you said you don't want to consider laser gyros.

Comment: @user71659 Equator? Who said anything about the equator? And why are you *still* pitching modern electronics on a quesiton where the OP said he liked my answer but it wasn't primitive enough? Hard audience. And you keep inserting dependencies as if they're required. Location is independent of distance *unless you care and happen to have a reference point in the same frame of reference as your location.* I know where I am my friend, but I don't know where you are and, unsurprisingly, don't know the distance between us. But, whatever you want to believe.

Comment: @JBH Longitude was previously is defined as distance from the Equator, so the equator is a critical notion in longitude. Because the Earth has an axial tilt of 23.4 degrees, the celestial sphere as observed from the ground rotates by 46.8 degrees over the course of a year. Thus, if you want to know your longitude better than that figure, you need to know time of year information, or at least observe in one place for multiple days. Latitude requires fine timing, longitude requires coarse time. There's no way around it.

Comment: @user71659 *[Latitude](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/latitude)* has a distance from the equator. [Longitude](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/longitude) runs from pole-to-pole and every longitudinal measurement bisects the equator. The equator has *nothing at all* to do with the measurement of or use of longitude. I think I'm done with this conversation.

Comment: @JBH I made a typo in my last comment. Again, it's plain wrong that you can figure out latitude without DOY data. Please do a little research on navigation, you have some severe misconceptions on how it works.

Comment: @user71659 I've never once suggested that we're trying to find Latitude. It appears this entire chain of comments is because you mistook longitude for latitude, not just in the last comment, but from your first comment. It's about time you owned up to your mistake and stopped pressing the irrelevant discussion about modern navigation.

Comment: @JBH You wrote `No, longitude is a location.` It is not a location because the people who had the most warships at the time arbitrarily defined the grid. Thus, you must have a fixed reference and measure the distance from that reference. An 18th-century view of longitude relies on the rotational axis of the Earth. That is less arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the sun is the easiest, and probably earliest, way to tell the time. But in no way the only primitive one. Clocks would be needed by any intelligent race early in its development, as to not get surprised by the dark. This would be fairly crucial to the survival of the species. If sundials are unavailable for obvious reasons, then I'd assume some alternatives would pop up much earlier.

**Water clocks** and **hourglasses** are rumoured to have existed several millennia BC, and would probably be invented earlier in the timeline in your setting. Alternatives like the Asian **Incense** clocks could be an option too.

Answer (score 4):

**Might be unreliable, but use how bight the sky is plus some math to tell the time**

We're going off relative brightness here

Start with how bright the sky looks, If it's bright, it's day, if it's dark, it's night.

Then, go with how bright or dark it is (this bit is tricky), if it's slightly dimmer than usual, then it's either early morning or late afternoon, if it's relatively bright out, it's most likely noon. (it may be hard to tell)

Use the light level of what came before now to determine the time of day. (Example: It was dark out earlier, now it's dim but light is here, so it's probably morning)

Divide this cycle up by any fraction to get hours, thus you have a basic system to tell the time, pair this up with either an hour glass or some other primitive non-light-based time measurement tool and you have a way to keep things on track

Comment: The "divide this up" step is going to be hard when they have no way of quantifying the duration between periods of brightness.

Comment: 50 shades of grey and there's a name for everyone of them,+1. *O'Dark-Thirty*

Answer (score 3):

## Cooking and Water Clocks

One of the first things that civilizations will want to have a good measurement of time for is cooking. Whoever is doing the cooking will want to cook something long enough, but not too long. At first there will be traditions passed down like "go get 10 buckets of water from the river, and when you're done getting the water, your meal will be cooked" but eventually this won't be good enough and people will invent....

The water clock.

This device will allow a consistent interval of time to be measured, and functions very much like an hourglass, but without the need for all the things you'd need to build and hourglass.

Now we have an egg timer (or whatever other time interval is good for cooking the food in your world)!

Comment: I'm not asking about how timing how long it takes to cook an egg. I'll clarify the question; I'm asking about agreeing to a meeting a month from now at 2:00 PM, or even a month from now in the afternoon. Water clocks were notoriously imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I have to mention sunstones.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunstone_(medieval)

Quick summary:

There is a debated device in history, a glassy stone with which it is theorized that you can locate the sun's position even in foggy and completly overcast skies.

Where does this theory come from? There are artifacts found on ship wrecks and ruins of old colonies and town and old written texts about such stones.

Also people tried to replicate this in the present and the results were mixed.

But the physical principles are there and it works. The question is more like "will it work every time and everywhere on the planet?".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to (reasonably accurately) detect the time of day if the skies are cloudy (especially if the thickness of the layer of clouds varies from day to day). It may be good enough to reset a time kept by other means if it drifts too far from the natural day, however.

If you keep time by other means (hourglass, water clock, mechanical clock mechanism) you have two problems- first to synchronize the various timepieces so that people will agree on the time. The second is to reset the time when it drifts too far from the natural time of day.

This is somewhat similar to the problems faced by the designers of [PTP (Precision Time Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol). Dealing with communication channels with delays of unknown and somewhat variable times (since it's presumably insufficient to have just one master clock in a primitive society without electronic communication).

They could have a master clock (which the chrono-priests reset from time to time, perhaps adjusting it in small increments in the middle of the night to correspond to their observations of the average sky illumination).

At daybreak or thereabouts (at a known time on the master clock) messengers could be sent out to far flung places with timing devices that are capable of roughly
measuring the time to and from the distant spot. The total time to and from could then be calculated and the remote clock adjusted to be synchronized fairly accurately with the master. The remote clocks need only keep time accurately enough between messenger visits and do not require the services of sky observers to reset the times. The jitter in messenger transit times could be compensated by only adjusting the remote times partially at each visit, so the adjustments are averaged.

Answer (score 1):

### Magnify the Sundial behaviour until it works

A sundial's problem on a cloudy day is that the light intensity isn't strong enough to produce a clear contrast of light and shadow on the dial.

So make it bigger, and invert it.

A human eye works by creating a large dark volume and a small aperture for light to enter.
If you create a large circular walled space and give it a partial roof with a hole in the middle, you'll find that the light forms a distinct spot-light effect in the room.

You can then tile your floor with markers for different times of day based on where the light starts and finishes over the course of the day.

It might look like a smaller version of this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When would they start to need clocks, and how would they satisfy this need?

**The Quest for Longitude**

As some comments have noted the need for precise time keeping depends on human activities.
Meetings, fairs, commerce, religious events could all be held without the need of knowing exactly the current hour (and minute).
Then humans started navigating around the globe and encountered a big problem: the need to determine their position on the surface of the globe.
On Earth latitude could be inferred quite easily by the maximum height of the sun on the horizon. But longitude while seafaring remained elusive for a long time. (*)
This was no small matter. In 1707 a fleet was shipwrecked because it could not determine its position accurately. [Scilly naval disaster of 1707](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilly_naval_disaster_of_1707)
This prompted even more the efforts from society to find ways to determine longitude.
The proposed method (and the one that was later successfuly implemented) was requiring to know the time exactly.

> To know one's longitude at sea, one needs to know what time it is aboard ship and also the time at the home port or another place of known longitude—at that very same moment. The two clock times enable the navigator to convert the hour difference into geographical separation. Since the earth takes 24 hours to revolve 360 degrees, one hour marks 1/24 of a revolution or 15 degrees. And so each hour's time difference between the ship and starting point marks a progress of fifteen degrees of longitude to the east or west.

> "Every day at sea, when the navigator resets his ship's clock to local noon when the sun reaches its highest point in the sky, and then consults the home port clock, every hour's discrepancy between them translates into another fifteen degrees of longitude. One degree of longitude equals four minutes of time the world over, although in terms of distance, one degree shrinks from 60.15 nautical miles or 111 km [Earth's circumference being 21,653.521 nautical miles, or 24,901.55 statute miles at the Equator], to virtually nothing at the poles

[Dava Sobel's - Longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_(book))

How the clock came to be, what challenges had to be overcome to have them running accurately abourd ships rolling in the ocean, with all kinds of weather, the struggles, the antagonists competing for the prize, falls and triumph. It's all in this throughly enjoyable book. I advise anyone here on worldbuilding to read it.

(*) In your world I don't know if the sun is visible at least as a vague circle in mid day, like you often have on a cloudy day. I assume its position can be determined as the light is bright enough on the planet for evolved life to develop.

TLDR: the first real NEED would be the quest for longitude. Anything before that was just a 'nice to have' instance.

Comment: The quest for longitude started thousands of years after the first clock was invented.

Comment: I know. But OP is asking for the NEED of it, as I reported in quote.

Comment: I'm the OP. I'm assuming an ancient need for clocks, not a nearly modern one. 300 years ago is essentially modern.

Comment: You are the OP's author, not the OP itself :) OP= Original Post.

Comment: Anyway my argument is that without any fabricated need for clocks for your race (e.g. religious ceremonies) the first real NEED for precise time keeping for mankind happened with the quest for longitude. All previous clocks devices were not exactly needed.

Comment: The first need for clocks occurred well before the quest for longitude. The quest for longitude turned out to be a quest for accurate clocks.

Comment: Are you talking about mankind now? Then I don't agree. State an exaple of a previous need for a clock. A clock, mind you, as in the title of your question. For scientific study, e.g. balistics other devices could be used, like a pendulum.

Comment: Dunkan, the need for clocks predated the need for longitude by many thousands of years. As the highest rated answer says, "Clocks don't exist to tell you when the sun will rise and set, they exist to coordinate the activities of people and events." The first human sailors never ventured far from shore, and they only went a few tens of kilometers from their home port. Presumably the same would apply on other worlds: clocks would be needed by early civilizations for many reasons well before the longitude problem arose.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see this NEED for clocks. Organization of the time would be done, when needed, by signals within the community. Calls, bells, trumpets and so on. When a time reference would be needed something like "after the morning prayer" would suffice.

Comment: I question why there has to be a NEED. It could just be more convenient than the alternative. Hell, it could even be a novelty. From Wikipedia: 

"The first known geared clock was invented by...Archimedes during the 3rd century BC. Archimedes created his astronomical clock[18] that was also a cuckoo clock with birds singing and moving every hour." 

Very little about this was motivated by need, certainly not lack of alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Going for super-simple here...

First a bit of Earth history, in old London, there was a lady who would tell you the time in exchange for money. I presume she got the actual time from Greenwich, then travelled to the centre of the city and "sold" time to people who couldn't get to Greenwich or didn't have a watch or way to maintain time between trips to Greenwich.

As noted, sand-based hour glasses, water clocks, etc are all a bit inaccurate. However, they were used extensively because they're often good enough. You can operate by sand-clock in your world. When the sun comes up, a timekeeper turns over a large sand clock (hour glass). This clock has been carefully crafted to be as regular as they can make it, and keeps running for as long as there's sunlight.

(You don't say if there are seasons - if there are, then the clock can have graduations on it which show when the day will end at different times of year).

People in the city can visit the clock to get the time, or perhaps "buy" it from enterprising people like the old lady in London. It is now possible to say "let's meet at 3pm", because everyone in the city is using the same "source of truth" (at least within a reasonable degree of accuracy). This works over a pretty broad geography - certainly 10s of miles.

Seasons (and so dates of the year) can be managed a similar way. Each day the time keeper turns the sand clock, (s)he also puts an extra slick into the ground, or puts an extra log on the pile or whatever to count the days (so far) this year. By all means break that counting up into chunks (like months or weeks). As we do, convention and prior knowledge tell us that (in the Northern hemisphere) you can expect it to be cold in January and have short days - the same thing is possible in your world (although measuring years gets tricky if there are no seasons - but in that case, a year can be "100 days" or whatever you like because it doesn't really matter where around its star the planet is).

The main principles here are:

- do the same thing every day/week/month/year - or whatever indicators of time passing you have (as others have noted, maybe the tides, or because the wind changes every few days or whatever).
- Get everyone to follow the same system of time (or at least everyone in a locality).
- Provide a way to know when the unit of time (eg. day) will end, so they can plan things throughout the day and not be half way through something when the light fades